# Center Justify Text in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have just started with LibGdx and I have figured out how to center text with it. Now I am having trouble with center justifying text. I was wondering if someone can help. I have attach my code for centering. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.tutorials.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class TextDemo extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    String myText;
    GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout();

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("myFont.fnt"));
        myText = "I took one, one cause you left me\n"
               + "Two, two for my family\n"
               + "Three, three for my heartache";
        layout.setText(font,myText);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        float x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - layout.width/2;
        float y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 + layout.height/2;

        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch,layout,x,y);//Center Text
        batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You already centered it. What is the distinction of center "justifying" it?

Comment: essential how it would look like if you would to center justify a paragraph in microsoft word.

Comment: I don't think Libgdx supports this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following setText() method instead and set targetWidth to screen width, Aligh.center, and set wrap to true. Also, set x = 0 so the text is centered across the whole screen.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout;

public void setText(BitmapFont font,
                java.lang.CharSequence str,
                Color color,
                float targetWidth,
                int halign,
                boolean wrap)
```

Updated example:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("myFont.fnt"));
    myText = "I took one, one cause you left me\n"
           + "Two, two for my family\n"
           + "Three, three for my heartache";
    layout.setText(font,myText,Color.BLACK,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Align.center,true);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float x = 0;
    float y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 + layout.height/2;

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch,layout,x,y);//Center Text
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `font.draw` method, use the following one instead...

```
public TextBounds drawMultiLine (Batch batch, CharSequence str, float x, float y, float alignmentWidth, HAlignment alignment)
```

`alignmentWidth` is the max width you want your text to take up. Any more than that and it will wrap. Set it to something stupidly high if you don't want wrapping.

'alignment' is the key thing and takes an `HAlignment` enum and can be either `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `CENTER`

The `batch`, `str`, `x` and `y` parameters are the same as you're already doing.

Comment: I tried that method and its not picking it up. I think that method is outdated.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I must've checked an old version. I'll take a look in a bit and find the current equivalent.